# Using {!User.FirstName} in Email template aiming for User object but return current user

Tags: email-template, user, email-alert, user-record, merge-field

I have an Email triggered on User object and want to say Dear User.FirstName something something.

In the merge field for Email template, User.FirstName will only reference the current User's first name. However, I need the selected User record's FirstName, thus the recipient's FirstName. How do I differentiate the two fields and make the correct merge field in the Email template?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this issue.
From the Email Template Editing page, there is an "Available Merge Fields". From that panel, people can choose whatever merge field for the Email template.

Here for my usage, the correct merge field should be "Target_User".

Receiving_User does not work as it is working for either Email triggered from Community or the Mass Email.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As of Mar 2024, when editing a Classic Email Template, "Target_User" is not an available merge field.  Using "Receiving_User" works correctly for my use case, which is passing a UserId as the `whoid` parameter to `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate()`.