# VF Email Template - Welcome New Member - {!$User.FirstName} displays created by user, not recipient

Tags: community, user, guest-user, merge-field, vf-email-template

As title suggests, I've created a **Welcome New Member** email using VF email template.

However the merge field `{!$User.FirstName}` and `{!$User.Username}` are displaying the created by user - i.e., our guest user.

Issue is similar to [this email template issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139492/using-user-firstname-in-email-template-aiming-for-user-object-but-return-curr) but VF email templates don't support `Receiving_User` or `Target_User`.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of the merge fields you use, depending on the email template.

For VF email templates:

- `{!$User.x}` references the user that created the community member.
- `{!Recipient.x}` references the recipient of the email. Note there is no `$` symbol.

Slightly confusing for other templates that use `{!Receiving_User.x}`.